# A reference request for zero-order hold (ZOH)

Tags: sampling, reference-request

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold):

> A zero-order hold reconstructs the following continuous-time waveform
>   from a sample sequence $x[n]$, assuming one sample per time interval
>   $T$: $$x_{\mathrm{ZOH}}(t)\,= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n]\cdot
>  \mathrm{rect} \left(\frac{t-T/2 -nT}{T} \right) \ $$ where
>   $\mathrm{rect}()$  is the rectangular function.

I'd like to find a good bibliographic reference for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a reference in the Wikipedia page; is that good enough?

Comment: Unfortunately, this reference is not of help to me.

Comment: Have you tried a quick search on books.google.com? I get [almost 600,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=zero-order+hold).

Comment: @MBaz, yes but I'd like to get a hint of a "good" reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally start with "Signals and Systems" by Oppenheim and Willsky. I have the second edition, and it has a good description of zero-order hold. This book is a must-have if you're interested in signals and systems. There is also a version that focuses on discrete signals. In addition, this book is probably available at most engineering libraries.